# Reading key/value pair text file efficiently with correct by construction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have few thousands of text files where each file is of following form:

```
Some Key: value1
Some Other Key: value2
Another Key: value3
... < 300+ such entries > ...
```

I want to read each of these files as dictionary and populate as a row in pandas dataframe. Though at this moment I am not sure if all the files have exact same keys or not but I'm hoping that there will not be too much variations as these files are logs from some tool.

What is the easiest way to read each file as dictionary so that it's correct by constructions?
As of now, my simple code is like following:

```
with open(log_data_file, mode="r") as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        keyval = line.strip().split(sep=":", maxsplit=3)
        
        if len(keyval) != 2:
            # some debug print
            continue
        
        data[keyval[0]] = keyval[1]
```

Possibly, I can add some logic to handle a line if that satisfies a regular expression. But beyond that, is there package in python where I can specify the grammar for the file and handle [iterate over list of (key, value)] the file only if the grammar is satisfied and file read is successful?

Comment: Your code is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm not that expert in Python, I'm checking if there's any better/easier way to do it.

Comment: There are parsers for standard file formats, like YAML, JSON, .INI, etc. This is not a standard config file, I don't think there's anything prewritten for it. It's so simple that it's not work bothering to write a library.

Comment: Your example file shows a space after the comma, you might want to strip that from the value. `data[keyval[0]] = keyval[1].strip()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
import re

read_buffer = """
Some Key: value1
Some Other Key: value2
Another Key: value3
... < 300+ such entries > ...
"""
regex = r"(?P<key>.+):\s(?P<value>\S+)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, read_buffer)
records = [match.groupdict() for match in matches]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df = df.T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df
```

[image]